# Python Geograpy is not finding Cities In USA

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, geograpy

I'm trying to find Countries/Cities on the webpage. So I used Geograpy.
but it is Not working properly.
Note: given website contains All the States in United States
Website = http://state.1keydata.com/

```
import geograpy
url='http://state.1keydata.com/'
place=geograpy.get_place_context(url=url)
print place.countries  #[]
print place.cities #[]
```

I have installed all the required packages like georapy,nltk(all)
I am using Anaconda.

Please guide if I'm wrong.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: 'not working properly' is a relative term. It'd be good for you, if elaborate the issue you're facing.

Comment: I'll edit the Question

Comment: Do you need to point to a detail page? The page http://state.1keydata.com/ does not list countries nor citites. Just states. So without knowing that exact module I'd expect an empty result.

Answer (score 2):

The page you would like to test is on site with an improper certificate which leads to a different problem i didn't try to solve. Instead i am using:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._state

as the example.

As a committer of geograpy3 to reproduce your issue i added a test to the most recent geograpy3 https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3/blob/master/tests/test_extractor.py:

```py
def testStackoverflow43322567(self):
        '''
        see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322567/python-geograpy-is-not-finding-cities-in-usa
        '''
        url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._state'
        e=Extractor(url=url)
        places=e.find_geoEntities()
        self.check(places,['Alabama','Virginia','New York'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you tested on doesn't contain any city or country names, so it's not surprising that you get empty results.

Comment: Please help me to find the states in that page

Comment: Try `place.regions` or `place.other`. Just reading off the project page...

Comment: The project is meant to extract city, region and country names out of *ordinary text.* Why are you testing it on a table of US states, which are none of these? Test it on something like the news text given in the project front page, and look for cities.

Comment: My project meant to extract country in the given webpage(whatever the page). i have to traverse their contact us page and find the webpage address(country). If country not there in the website i have to fine the state or city. help of those state/city i need to find their country. i have a code, it can able to traverse contact us page. Please guide me if possible. Thank you in Advance @alexis

Answer (score 0):

I found that re-installing all required packages manually, as well as adding a tweak to the geography library files did the trick. [Check this](https://electricarchaeology.ca/2015/10/14/extracting-places-with-python/) for more details.

1. lxml
2. beautifulsoup
3. pillow

Next, I ran the command `python nltk.download()` from the command line

After doing these steps, I got another error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ExtractLocation_geograpy.py", line 5, in <module>
    places = geograpy.get_place_context(text = text1)
  File "C:\Users\Avardhan\Documents\CVS_POC\.env\lib\site-packages\geograpy\__init__.py", line 11, in get_place_context
    pc.set_cities()
  File "C:\Users\Avardhan\Documents\CVS_POC\.env\lib\site-packages\geograpy\places.py", line 174, in set_cities
    self.country_cities[country.name] = []
```

By replacing `country.name` with `country_name`, I was able to finally get the required output.